# jQuery animation isnt repeating

Tags: javascript

Im pretty sure that my jQuery should below should work but when I use it in a Drupal site the animation doesn't repeat like it should.

http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/t/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 960) {

    function fadeOutFunc() {
        $('.image-list .bottom').delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.image-list .bottom').delay(1000).fadeIn(500,fadeOutFunc);
        });
    }

    fadeOutFunc();

    //  jQuery('.image-list .bottom').css('opacity','0.6');


    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting js code using Drupal Behaviours

```
(function($, Drupal)
{
  Drupal.behaviors.animation = {
    attach:function()
    {
      if ( $(window).width() > 960) {

      function fadeOutFunc() {
        $('.image-list .bottom').delay(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
          $('.image-list .bottom').delay(1000).fadeIn(500,fadeOutFunc);
        });
    }

    fadeOutFunc();
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

Comment: With the new code the animation doenst fire at all.